# Chrome Extension Storage API Error Handling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

Title says it all essentially, I know how to detect errors using Chrome's `runtime.lastError` property using a conditional; however, I'm not sure what I should do from then on.

For instance, say I have an application where I set a `settings` property on install:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({settings: ...}, () => {
  if (runtime.lastError) {
    // What to do here?
  }
});
```

Generally, in other projects, I usually handle errors by setting defaults, etc.

Preferably, there's a way to ensure that the value is set eventually.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you want to make sure something is set to a default value, then you can check if the settings exist, and if not, put them in as default, and repeat the check recursively, every time any kind of function is run.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Recursively meaning placing it within the callback? I would assume that would cause issues if errors are constant.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon However, I agree with your sentiment to set the default when it does not exist. I was hoping there was a better way than having checks all over to set up defaults that should exist anyway.

Comment: If an error occurs in chrome.storage it means you've exceeded the quota for the entire storage or for an individual value, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-sync).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the info! So say I was running sync.set on the runtime.installed listener, would it essentially be guaranteed that no error would occur? Since I won't store data larger the max quota, items greater than the max quota, would have only one write, etc. I thought perhaps there would be other reasons for errors to show up (out of my control).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.